# Errors Resetting mysql root Password

Tags: mysql, passwords, reset

Version info: mysql  Ver 8.0.19-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

I have tried no less than 3 walkthroughs, and am getting nowhere.  Forgive me if I've not found the answer after 3 hours.

I'm trying to reset a forgotten root password.  Here's the last thing I've tried:

1. sudo service mysql stop
2. sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &

[1] 8047 is returned

3. mysql -u root

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

These last instructions came from https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-change-and-recover-a-mysql-root-password/  in the section "Recover your MySQL password", and these instructions were last updated April 26, 2019.

Again, this is the latest 'recipe' that I've tried. There have been others, all have failed. Help?

Comment: Try the [official documentation on password resets](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html). Its actually kept up to date.

Comment: This was actually where I began.  Step 1 - "Log on to your system as the Unix user that the MySQL server runs as (for example, mysql). "  may have caused my cascade of errors.  I am logged in as root.  This is my local system.  How do I retrieve this information?

Comment: The only thing that sort of works is:
$ sudo bash
# service mysql start
# mysql -uroot -p (and password works here)

From there I can change the password, but I cannot use it as a regular user or sudoer.

Comment: Include details in your question; clearly, and precisely.

Comment: Which details should I include?